# JSONDecode :Error JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at line 1

Tags: python, json

I have around 9 pdf in my directory. However, for a couple of PDFs, it gives me the error **(JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at line 1 column 62466 (char 62465)).** Rather than encoding= 'unicode_escape' if I use 'rb' it gives an error **(positional argument following keyword argument)**. But If I am using encoding= 'unicode_escape', it works fine but for a couple of pdf, it throws a JSONDecodeError.

```
import tabula as tb
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import os
import json

for file_name in os.listdir(r"W:\test\Documentation\PDF\Folder"):
    print(file_name)
    dfs = tb.read_pdf(r'W:\\test\Documentation\PDF\\Folder\\'+file_name, pages='all',encoding= 'unicode_escape')
    print(dfs)
```

How can I resolve the above error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8JFM.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsWaY.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us an example PDF or two to shed light on what is possibly happening?

Comment: Apologies, I am not allowed to share the PDF as it's under NDA. However, I can explain, that the PDF contains majorly tables there is no text. There are email addresses, latitude/longitude, date,s, etc.

Comment: Could you show the full traceback to the error? I think you will need to patch `tabula` a bit so you can get rid of the stray control characters.

Comment: I have added the images of the error in the question, please check

Comment: Why are using encoding as `unicode_escape`? This should be the encoding that the parent python process is using to communicate with the child tabula process. If in doubt it should be `import locale; locale.getpreferredencoding()`. Which will likely be `cp1252` if the language your OS uses is English (as you appear to be using Windows file paths).

Comment: Thank you, but it still shows the same error